# Is there any cap or soft cap for weapon proficiency?

Tags: the-surge

On wiki I've found weapons damage stats up to 20 level of proficiency, but [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/378540/discussions/0/1290690669221937936/?ctp=2) people report having up to 29 level.

Is there any cap or recommended soft cap for weapons proficiencies?